# DIVs with style.display none still showing up

Tags: javascript, css

on loading a page I have some javascript code which hides some layers

```
document.getElementById(layerName).style.display = "none";
```

Everything works well, but in IE and in Opera these DIVs are showing up for the first few milliseconds while the page loads. After that, it's back to normal.

Is there a way around that?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume your circumstances prevent you from styling them directly via CSS (inline or external)?

Answer (score 2):

If you run code when the page loads, it will not run until the page finishes loading.

Instead, you can put the code in a `<script>` block below the elements, without handling `onload`.

Or you just use CSS.

Comment: I'm guessing this is why about 90% of people start using jQuery/any other framework.  It's why I did!

Answer (score 1):

you could set display to false in you HTML code

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way around that?

It's called CSS:

```
.layer {
display:'none';
}
```

This problem occurs because of the way the browser renders the page. CSS is first before Javascript. So always try to do things in CSS when possible.

Answer (score 0):

place this script immediately below the div placed. you will almost clear the problem